# How can I find the log of my Webapp when running by other people?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

My Webapp is a `doGet()` function returning a `HtmlOutput` object to provide Get service.

It has been published for some days and has been run more than one hundred times.

Don't know why there was one time it ran failure this morning.The people who get the failure said it just show an error message on the page like

> "Error:........"

and she didn't record it.I don't know where what's wrong, and I can't see any record in my dashboard or that people's dashboard.

So where can I some information about that?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable error log go to **View -> Stackdriver Error Reporting** in GAS editor.

Comment: I found it in View -> Stackdriver Error Reporting in GAS editor.Thank you very much!